# #1064 error in importing database php mysql localhost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have backup of my live site's database. I want to run it on localhost. I tried to import the back up database that I craeted in phpmyadmin/localhost. But I am getting error something like this:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

```
"http://www.w' at line 1
```

Can Any one help me....

Comment: Perhaps you could include the beginning of your dump?

Comment: I tried to dump 2 times so I dont think that is the wrong thing...

Comment: What I meant was that you should include the beginning of your database dump in your question, so people can try to spot any problems. Just saying that you have an error in your sql syntax doesn't say anything.

Comment: This doesn't look like an SQL file, but as Krister Andersson suggested, you should post a few lines so we can see exactly what you are dealing with. How did you create the backup? What file type does it claim to be (is there an extension on the file)?

Comment: Isaac Bennetch, your suggestion helped me. Can you answer so that I can approve as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an SQL file, but as Krister Andersson suggested, you should post a few lines so we can see exactly what you are dealing with. How did you create the backup? What file type does it claim to be (is there an extension on the file)?